# When will the PLayList functionality mentioned on this session be available in the pierfrancescosoffritti library?

Tags: kotlin

I'm using pierfrancescosoffritti library to implement youtube player on my app. Also trying to implement Playlist functionality and the override methods mentioned in this session are still not implemented. Does anyone know when they will be implemented?

https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/pull/1006/files#diff-271670a6237b7cb45587ab7ca17ea41063f5f5665bf7b44ba9ea371dc76b344b

Used the latest 12.0.0 version of PierfrancescoSoffritti library but none of this functionality is available?
Thank you